# Reference Constant as String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my `/lib` directory in Rails 5, I have a class that is within the namespace of a Ruby module.

I can reference the class with the following code:

```
OrderSyncers::Marketplaces::Walmart.new
```

In my Rails model I have a marketplace column that contains a marketplace name such as "Walmart". I am trying to reference the `Walmart` class. Note: the `Walmart` class is a subclass of `OrderSyncers::OrderSync.new`.

In ruby I can successfully call a class with the following code:

```
Object.cont_get("Test").new
```

However, when I try to reference that class name within the namespace reference, I get an error.

```
OrderSyncers::Marketplaces::Object.const_get("Walmart").new
```

Error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant OrderSyncers::Marketplaces::Object)
```

The reason I am wanting to use `Object.const_get("string")` is so that I can use the fields I have in my database to initialize the correct subclass of `OrderSyncers::OrderSync`.

Comment: you are talking about `Walmart` class but using `Object` which probably does not exist in that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you add the `::Object`? You don't need it.

```
OrderSyncers::Marketplaces.const_get("Walmart").new
```

Comment: How does this work? Can you explain? This looks like a function call on `Marketplaces` but that would make no sense. It does however work. Thanks

Comment: @CannonMoyer: Why would it make less sense than calling `const_get` on Object? Same thing happens here.

Comment: I guess what confuses me about this is that `Marketplaces.const_get` looks like nothing more than a class method so the syntax is rather confusing. I don't quite understand how `Marketplaces.const_get("Walmart")` returns `Marketplaces::Walmart`. It would seem to me that it would return `::Walmart` but again that wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: @CannonMoyer: because Walmart is a constant which belongs to Marketplaces (is nested in it). "Marketplaces.const_get looks like nothing more than a class method" - that's precisely what it is. Well, actually it's a [module method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get), so it should not be surprising that a module has this method.

Comment: @CannonMoyer: don't worry, it will click one day. In the meanwhile, maybe grab a copy of "programming ruby"

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the help!